# JSON Serialization slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a very simple ASP.NET WebAPI endpoint that does one call to our database, and return those rows as JSON. The response size is around 180KB (180 records).

When I deploy that project to Azure that call takes around 100ms which is fine but only on the first minutes, then suddenly it slows down to 24 seconds consistently.

On the code below I'm serializing the object manually instead of just returning the modal directly (using webapi JSON serializer which is the same), for the sake of understanding where time is being spent.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{stuffId}/toys")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IQueryable<FooModel>))]
public HttpResponseMessage GetStuff(int stuffId)
{
    var stuff = QueryProcessor.Execute(new GetStuffByIdQuery
    {
        StuffId = stuffId,
    });

    var mappedResult = stuff.Map();

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mappedResult);

    response.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    return response;
}
```

**And what I realized is surprising, the time is being spent on the Serialization method.**

`var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mappedResult);`

What is more confusing is that, deploying the same code to another website on Azure other than our production environment, or running it locally pointing to production databases it's always fast.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: If this doesn't slow down on other Environments you have in Azure then surely finding what is different between those environments will help in find this. Knowing what type 'stuff' is would help with answering this. If its a massive object graph then this could be one reason. Also how do you know it's the SerializeObject call that is the slow line?

Comment: @matt_lethargic The environments are exactly the same, the only difference is that the one where the problem happens is "Production", the other is "Pre Prodution" where we don't get that much traffic. I know is the SerializeObject call because I created another endpoint with exactly the same code but without doing the "SerializeObject" and then it's fast.

Comment: And stuff is? Also what does stuff.Map() do. If it's using some object mapper and the execution is delayed until the serializer is called then it might be that that's causing the slow down and not the serializer. Having written many production api's using Newtonsoft Json (which I assume you're using) I know that the serialization is quick unless you're doing something daft before it.

Comment: Have to tried using application insights? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/application-insights

Comment: @matt_lethargic stuff is a model with around 35 properties. Which is being mapped to another model with more or less the same number of properties. The stuff.Map() is basically assigning those from one to another manually. I'm going to look into application insights. Thanks

Comment: @matt_lethargic thanks a lot mate ! Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the idea that matt_lethargic pointed out, I discovered that there was something being done on the `.map` call that was causing the issue.

I was mislead by the fact that the execution was being delayed, so doing stopwatches I was not getting into the exact problem.

Basically there was a instantiation per each row doing made on the `ResourceManager` to access some values from a resources file.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. A good general rule for mapping stuff is always have all the data before you map and never call a db or resource during mapping. Happy programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
var mappedResult = stuff.Map().ToList();
```

This worked for me